# Get element to scroll back to top when child element clicked

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

I'm trying to get a parent element to scroll back to the top of itself when an anchor tag is clicked inside of the parent element. This is my code so far, using scrollTop().

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".sidebar-nav nav .menu .menu-item a").click(function() {
        $(".sidebar-nav nav .menu").scrollTop = 0;
    });
}):
```

However this doesn't seem to be working, I've tried implementing code from other answers given on questions relating to what I'm trying to do but to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with `$(this).closest('.menu').scrollTop(0)`

Comment: @Brewal That has worked thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brewel suggested `$(this).closest('.menu').scrollTop(0);` which worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(".sidebar-nav nav .menu").scrollTop = 0;
```

with

```
$(".sidebar-nav nav .menu").scrollTop(0);
```

---

Readup the official documentation on `.scrollTop()`: http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, @Brewel's suggestion worked however I can only assume yours would work just as well as it was my syntax error!